# How to get the server url in blazor webassembly app?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly

I have a .NET Web Api Server and a Blazor Webassembly Client.

My problem is, that I don't know where to set the server base url on the client side. If I would deploy it to a docker container, my guess would be, that it should come from an environment variable.

The only solution that I found is through:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

At least in my local dev environment this obviously routes me always to the frontend base url.

So where do I need to set the backend url or how can I read out the env variable if it is deployed to a docker container so I can use it in signalR or REST-Calls?

Answer (score 2):

In Wasm you can access the 'HostEnvironment' with

```
if (builder.HostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new 
    Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
}

if (builder.HostEnvironment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("SomeotherAddress") });
}

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

you'll need to set the env for example : `dotnet run --environment Production` [doc's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I set the custom base address or define own environment variables? I did not find a thing in regrads to this in the documentation?

Comment: @Codix, the code above shows how to set the base address ? as for how to set the env variable it depends on the underlying OS, perhaps post a separate question